# how to convert ServiceEndpointElement to ServiceEndpoint

Tags: wcf, configuration, mef

I am trying to load a set of WCF services in Service Host using MEF.
I implememnted a custom service host which needs to create a ServiceDescription.

For creating that, I need a list of endpoints each service exposes. In my case, each service DLL exposes a DLL Config file which has a service model section for the services in DLL.

I can read the section of each service using MEF imported type as follows :

```cs
        var filemap = new System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap ();

        filemap.ExeConfigFilename = serviceType.Assembly.Location + ".config";

        System.Configuration.Configuration config =
        System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration
        (filemap,
         System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        var serviceModel = System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup (config);
```

Now,
I would like to generate a List so that my host can start using the exposed endpoints.

So, I do the following :

```cs
        System.Generic.List<ServiceEndpoint> endpointsList = new List<ServiceEndpoint> ();

        var serviceModel = System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup (config);

        foreach (System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceElement se in serviceModel.Services.Services) {
              foreach (ServiceEndpointElement endpointElement in se.Endpoints) {
                       ServiceEndpoint endpoint;

                        // I need help here.

                          endpointsList.Add (endpoint);
               }
         }
```

Please see "I need help here" in above code.
How should I fill up properties of endpoint object above from endpointElement above?
Is there some converter available from .NET? I guess this must be the same which .NET internally uses to load the ServiceHost from configuration file.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to accomplish this?

Comment: This is the closest solution I was yet able to find on the subject of manual processing of WCF configuration, though it does not deal with endpoints themselves - [Getting WCF Bindings and Behaviors from any config source](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2010/05/11/getting-wcf-bindings-and-behaviors-from-any-config-source.aspx)